# Google Cloud Storage upload giving error C# MVC application .Net FrameWork 4.6.1

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, google-cloud-storage

We are using Google Cloud sample to upload .tmx file in google cloud storage

All the Google API and Google Cloud Storage are installed from nuget that too with latest version installed.

Link : https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/uploading-objects#storage-upload-object-code-sample

Code :

```
using Google.Cloud.Storage.V1;
using System;
using System.IO;

public class UploadFileSample
{
    public void UploadFile(
        string bucketName = "your-unique-bucket-name",
        string localPath = "my-local-path/my-file-name",
        string objectName = "my-file-name")
    {
        var storage = StorageClient.Create();
        using var fileStream = File.OpenRead(localPath);
        storage.UploadObject(bucketName, objectName, null, fileStream);
        Console.WriteLine($"Uploaded {objectName}.");
    }
}
```

---

And it is giving error :

An exception of type 'System.MissingMethodException' occurred in Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Method not found: 'System.Action`1<System.Net.Http.HttpRequestMessage> Google.Apis.Upload.ResumableUploadOptions.get_ModifySessionInitiationRequest()'.

Can you help how to resolve this

Comment: That suggests you've got a dependency issue - that the version of Google.Apis you're using isn't the same as the version that Google.Cloud.Storage transitively depends on. Please give more details about your project type, how you're running it, your dependencies etc.

Comment: (I'd note that ResumableUploadOptions.ModifySessionInitiationRequest has been present for a *very* long time, which suggests you've got an ancient Google.Apis dependency somehow...)

Comment: all the packages related to Google Cloud are updated to latest version from Nuget package 

Google.Cloud.Storage.V1.3.5.0

Google.Apis.Storage.v1.1.52.0.2234

Google.Apis.1.52.0

Comment: I suspect you're really *not* getting Google.Apis.1.52.0. Please have a look in your bin directory for Google.Apis.dll, right-click and choose properties, then find the file version in "Details".

Comment: But fundamentally, we need more context - please *edit your question* to provide as much information about the context as possible. What version of .NET are you using? What version of ASP.NET? How are you specifying the dependencies, and what are they? Do you have any assembly binding redirects?

Comment: i have seen it is File Version: 1.52.0.0

Comment: Well we definitely won't be able to make more progress without more context then, because that version of the DLL *absolutely definitely* contains the method (from a property) that the exception says doesn't exist. If you can provide a way of reproducing the problem, I'll happily take a look.

Comment: Here's one way to check whether you've really got the right version: replace your method body with `var options = new ResumableUploadOptions { ModifySessionInitiationrequest = null };` - does that compile? What happens if you try to execute it?

Comment: @JonSkeet no error after replacing code compiled and ran also with this

Comment: Okay, then it really *shouldn't* be a problem for it to work from the client library. Ah, unless you've got a different version of HttpRequest somehow. (Again, this is where it would *really* help if you'd provide a [mcve].)